# How to import webpack bundled js file in Angular

Tags: angular, typescript, pdf.js, pdfjs-dist

I have a js file where all modules are bundled using webpack,I want to use that file in angular.
File is too big so i have pasted few lines of code here.

[image]

Comment: what is this file? how and why do you want to use that file in Angular? are you using angular CLI?

Comment: It is a webpack bundled js file, i want to call modules inside it and expose them to outside components. i am using angular CLI.

Answer (score 0):

As an example like below, in `angular.json` file, `CSS` and `JavaScript` files are included under `"styles":[]` and `"scripts":[]` respectively:

```
 "styles": [
    "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css",
    "src/styles.css"
  ],
  "scripts": [
      "node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js",
      "node_modules/popper.js/dist/umd/popper.min.js",
      "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"
  ]
```

So, if you have your own `JavaScript` file you can add the file path here in `angular.json` file at the same place in `"scripts":[]`.

**EDIT**

You can import your own `JavaScript` file in `polyfills.ts` or even better import it only when you need it in your specific components.

Comment: I tried adding js file in scripts section but no luck, there are other few dependencies which are throwing error. Can we expose webpack bundled modules to outside components?

Comment: Can you please check the EDIT portion of my answer?